# Beautifulsoup Parsing- detail info

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I already asked a question, but it seems my explnation was not clear..
So, I am asking again with more detail info.

```
<h2 class="sectionTitle">
CORPORATE HEADQUARTERS  </h2>
277 Park Avenue<br />
New York, New York 10172
<br /><br />United States<br /><br />
```

I would like to extract only New York, New York without postal code 10172

And this is another question..

```
<h2 class="sectionTitle">
BACKGROUND</h2>
He graduated Blabala 
</span>
```

I would like to extract only He graduated Blabla

I have been spending few days, so I feel I could become crazy..
Please help me.. thank you for your kind help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need more detail to write a good regex.

For example, if you want to extract the second line of "CORPORATE HEADQUARTERS" without a postal code that always exists, it can be written like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> html = '''
... <h2 class="sectionTitle">
... CORPORATE HEADQUARTERS  </h2>
... 277 Park Avenue<br />
... New York, New York 10172
... <br /><br />United States<br /><br />
... 
... <h2 class="sectionTitle">
... BACKGROUND</h2>
... He graduated Blabala
... </span>
... '''
>>> re.search('(?s)<h2 class="sectionTitle">\s*CORPORATE HEADQUARTERS\s*</h2>.*?<br />([^<>]+) \d+', html).group(1).strip()
'New York, New York'
>>> re.search('(?s)<h2 class="sectionTitle">\s*BACKGROUND\s*</h2>([^<>]+)', html).group(1).strip()
'He graduated Blabala'
```

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse html? Sounds like a great idea!

Comment: Regex is much faster and more tolerant. But you need to be very very careful. It's only suitable for specific site.

Comment: thank you so much! but I don't know why.. it doesn't work and it represents 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: re.search return None if regex can not find a match. You need to handle this in real code.

Comment: hmmm I just copied and pasted as you wrote.. ohhh

Comment: Have you removed the "... " prompt?

Comment: oh it is working well.. thank you.. but when I run this program in a website I would like to apply, it doesn't work.. it said "TypeError: expected string or buffer"  the webpage is http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private/person.asp?personId=668561&privcapId=160900&previousCapId=285930&previousTitle=LOEWS%20CORP

Answer (score 0):

You should use a combination of [`tag.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#contents) with `.split('\n') to split on lines and`.rsplit(' ', 1)` to split only the right most space-separated string.